# bindBidirectional with function?

Tags: java, javafx, listener

I know you can use NumberBindings to, say, bind x to y such that if x is 10, then y is 20.  I want to do something more complicated, and I'm not sure if I can use bindings to achieve that goal.

I want to have two sets of three sliders, which translate a vector in 3D space, in either Cartesian or spherical coordinates.  What I'd like to see happen is whenever one of the values in the Cartesian slider is modified, the values on the spherical sliders are changed accordingly, and vice versa.  So changing one value in one set of three leads to changing three values in the other set of three.

I would think to try this using ChangeListeners, but I get into loops where changing A leads to recalculating B leads to recalculating A and I get this website's eponymous error.  I also thought to try having one vector object which has a bidirectional binding to both sets of sliders, but I get the same problem with that.

Another thing I thought about is to have that ChangeListener first see if any of the sliders in one set are being changed by the user vs being changed by the listener, but I haven't figured out how to do that, and even if so I suspect it might not be an efficient way to do it.  Do I want to use an ActionListener instead?

Is this something I can do?

EDIT: Added MWE

```
import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;

public class BindingProblemMWE {
    private DoubleProperty xProperty;
    public DoubleProperty xProperty() {
        if (xProperty == null) {xProperty = new SimpleDoubleProperty(0);}
        return xProperty;
    }

    private DoubleProperty yProperty;
    public DoubleProperty yProperty() {
        if (yProperty == null) {yProperty = new SimpleDoubleProperty(0);}
        return yProperty;
    }

    private DoubleProperty zProperty;
    public DoubleProperty zProperty() {
        if (zProperty == null) {zProperty = new SimpleDoubleProperty(0);}
        return zProperty;
    }

    private DoubleProperty azProperty;
    public DoubleProperty azProperty() {
        if (azProperty == null) {azProperty = new SimpleDoubleProperty(0);}
        return azProperty;
    }

    private DoubleProperty elProperty;
    public DoubleProperty elProperty() {
        if (elProperty == null) {elProperty = new SimpleDoubleProperty(0);}
        return elProperty;
    }

    private DoubleProperty rhoProperty;
    public DoubleProperty rhoProperty() {
        if (rhoProperty == null) {rhoProperty = new SimpleDoubleProperty(0);}
        return rhoProperty;
    }

    private ChangeListener<Number> recalculateSpherical() {
        return (obs, ov, nv) -> {

            double x = xProperty().doubleValue();
            double y = yProperty().doubleValue();
            double z = zProperty().doubleValue();

            azProperty.set(calculateAz(x,y,z));
            elProperty.set(calculateEl(x,y,z));
            rhoProperty.set(calculateRho(x,y,z));
        };
    }

    private ChangeListener<Number> recalculateCartesian() {
        return (obs, ov, nv) -> {
            double az = azProperty().doubleValue();
            double el = elProperty().doubleValue();
            double rho = rhoProperty().doubleValue();

            xProperty.set(calculateX(az, el, rho));
            yProperty.set(calculateY(az, el, rho));
            zProperty.set(calculateZ(az, el, rho));
        };
    }

    private void initialize() {

        xProperty().addListener(recalculateSpherical());
        yProperty().addListener(recalculateSpherical());
        zProperty().addListener(recalculateSpherical());

        azProperty().addListener(recalculateCartesian());
        elProperty().addListener(recalculateCartesian());
        rhoProperty().addListener(recalculateCartesian());

        xProperty().set(1);
        yProperty().set(1);
        zProperty().set(1);

    }

    private static double calculateX(double az, double el, double rho) {
        return rho*Math.sin(el)*Math.cos(az);}

    private static double calculateY(double az, double el, double rho) {
        return rho*Math.sin(el)*Math.sin(az);}

    private static double calculateZ(double az, double el, double rho) {
        return rho*Math.cos(el);}

    private static double calculateAz(double x, double y, double z) {
        return Math.atan2(y, x);}

    private static double calculateEl(double x, double y, double z) {
            return Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(x*x + y*y), z);}

    private static double calculateRho(double x, double y, double z) {
        return Math.sqrt(x*x + y*y + z*z);}


    public static void main(String [] args) {
        BindingProblemMWE mwe = new BindingProblemMWE();
        mwe.initialize();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Tomas Mikula has a library called [ReactFX](https://github.com/TomasMikula/ReactFX) which includes versions of JavaFX properties that generally work a lot better, and have the functionality you're looking for. Look at the `Val` and `Var` interfaces in the `org.reactfx.value` package. It looks like this is not under active maintenance, however.

The reason you see stack overflow exceptions in your example is that the change to each individual coordinate prompts a change to the coordinates in the other representation. Those *individual* changes are, of course, not inverses of each other, so you end up in an infinite loop of changes. (E.g., changing `x` results in a change in `az`, leading to the spherical representation being a different point to the one that the change in `x` represented, so this results in a further change in `x`, etc.) If you "atomize" the three changes to each representation, then in theory you stop the infinite recursion, as long as the two functions are exact inverses of each other.

Probably the best way to achieve this is to use a single object here instead of three different values. This has the additional advantage that when you change the point in 3D space, you observe a single change instead of three changes. So here I'd use `ObjectProperty<T>` for some appropriate type `T`.

The last point to note is that when you're working with floating point arithmetic as you are in your example, you are still vulnerable to stack overflow exceptions as the numerical errors in the computation prevent the functions from being exact inverses of each other.
Your idea to set and unset a flag when these are changing is the right approach; you just have to figure out where to keep that flag. In this example I create a separate `BidirectionalBinding` class that allows you to store the flag and also to unbind both listeners via a method in the class.

```
import java.util.function.Function;

import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.Property;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;

public class BidirectionalBinding<T,U> {

    private final Property<T> source ;
    private final Property<U> target ;

    private boolean changing = false ;
    private ChangeListener<? super T> sourceListener;
    private ChangeListener<? super U> targetListener;

    public BidirectionalBinding(Property<T> source, Property<U> target, 
            Function<T,U> mapping, Function<U,T> inverseMapping) {
        this.source = source ;
        this.target = target ;

        target.setValue(mapping.apply(source.getValue()));

        sourceListener = (obs, oldSourceValue, newSourceValue) -> {
            if (! changing) {
                changing = true ;
                target.setValue(mapping.apply(newSourceValue));
            }
            changing = false ;
        };
        source.addListener(sourceListener);

        targetListener = (obs, oldTargetValue, newTargetValue) -> {
            if (! changing) {
                changing = true ;
                source.setValue(inverseMapping.apply(newTargetValue));
            }
            changing = false ;
        };
        target.addListener(targetListener);

    }

    public void unbind() {
        source.removeListener(sourceListener);
        target.removeListener(targetListener);
    }

    public Property<T> getSource() {
        return source;
    }

    public Property<U> getTarget() {
        return target;
    }

    public static class Cartesian {
        private final double x ;
        private final double y ;
        private final double z ;
        public Cartesian(double x, double y, double z) {
            super();
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.z = z;
        }
        public double getX() {
            return x;
        }
        public double getY() {
            return y;
        }
        public double getZ() {
            return z;
        }
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return String.format("[x=%f, y=%f, z=%f]", x, y, z);
        }
        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (! (o instanceof Cartesian)) return false ;
            if (o == this) return true ;
            Cartesian other = (Cartesian) o ;
            return x == other.x && y == other.y && z == other.z ;
        }

    }

    public static class Spherical {
        private final double az ;
        private final double el ;
        private final double rho ;
        public Spherical(double az, double el, double rho) {
            super();
            this.az = az;
            this.el = el;
            this.rho = rho;
        }
        public double getAz() {
            return az;
        }
        public double getEl() {
            return el;
        }
        public double getRho() {
            return rho;
        }
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return String.format("[az=%f, el=%f, rho=%f]", az, el, rho);
        }
        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (! (o instanceof Spherical)) return false ;
            if (o == this) return true ;
            Spherical other = (Spherical) o ;
            return az == other.az && el == other.el && rho == other.rho ;
        }           

    }

    // test case:
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ObjectProperty<Cartesian> cartesian = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(new Cartesian(0,0,0));
        ObjectProperty<Spherical> spherical = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(new Spherical(0,0,0));

        Function<Cartesian, Spherical> cartesianToSpherical = cart -> {
            double x = cart.getX();
            double y = cart.getY();
            double z = cart.getZ();
            double az = Math.atan2(y, x);
            double el = Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(x*x + y*y), z);
            double rho = Math.sqrt(x*x + y*y + z*z) ;
            return new Spherical(az, el, rho);
        };

        Function<Spherical, Cartesian> sphericalToCartesian = spher -> {
            double az = spher.getAz();
            double el = spher.getEl();
            double rho = spher.getRho();
            double x = rho*Math.sin(el)*Math.cos(az);
            double y = rho*Math.sin(el)*Math.sin(az);
            double z = rho*Math.cos(el);
            return new Cartesian(x, y, z);
        };

        BidirectionalBinding<Cartesian, Spherical> binding = new BidirectionalBinding<>(cartesian, spherical,
                cartesianToSpherical, sphericalToCartesian);

        System.out.println(cartesian.get());
        System.out.println(spherical.get());
        System.out.println("\nSetting cartesian to [1,1,1]");
        cartesian.set(new Cartesian(1, 1, 1));
        System.out.println(cartesian.get());
        System.out.println(spherical.get());
        System.out.println("\nSetting sphercial to [pi/4, pi/4, 1]");
        spherical.set(new Spherical(Math.PI/4, Math.PI/4, 1));
        System.out.println(cartesian.get());
        System.out.println(spherical.get());

        binding.unbind();
    }
}
```

If you want to maintain the three separate properties for the three coordinates, in each representation, then I think you could still use this general strategy, but you'd probably need a specific class that took the six properties as fields and was specific to this problem, instead of being generic as in this example.

With ReactFX (and the `Cartesian` and `Spherical` classes I defined), I think you can do something like

```
ObjectProperty<Cartesian> cartesian = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(new Cartesian(0,0,0));
Property<Spherical> = Var.mapBidirectional(cartesian, cartesianToSpherical, sphericalToCartesian);
```

If Tomas is still active on this site, he'll likely give you some additional ideas (and probably more robust implementations than the one I suggest).

Comment: I had JUST found a fairly similar solution, and had started to implement it!  See http://carl-witt.de/customized-bidirectional-bindings-in-javafx/  I think it is running into the floating point issue you describe, however.  I don't get a stack overflow, but it does run many times (presumably it converges).

Would the solution be to change `if(alreadyCalled)` to `if(alreadyCalled || almostEqual(oldValue, newValue))`, where `almostEqual` is some function input to bindBidirectional for both types A and B? (using the wording from the cited example)

Comment: @FrankHarris I think mine only runs once per change. If it's running many times, it may be because your sliders are causing lots of changes. IIRC, sliders have a `valueChanging` property (essentially, the user is still sliding the slider), which you could check and not update the point while it's still changing.